# jQuery autocomplete styling working in Chrome but not Firefox or IE

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, autocomplete

I have implemented a jquery auto complete input box on my web form.

it works perfectly across all platforms. my problem is that I am using jquery ui for styling. the javascript generated drop down list is styled correctly in chrome but in Firefox and IE it is a completely unstyled li list.

Why is this and how can I correct it?

Should there not be a reason, how can I generate my own styling for the li list and where should this style come from?

my head syntax is:

```
   <link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" media="screen" type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/customer_autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`customer_autocomplete.js` is simply :

```
$(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "sales_orders/get_customers" 
  });
});
```

an example image of each browser shown below, all exactly same code and header information.

firefox 13.1
[image: firefox]

IE 10
[image: internet explorer]

Chrome 25.0
[image: google chrome]

help appreciated as always

**Rendered HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         test
      </title>
   <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://domain.com/application/assets/images/favicon.ico' />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">      
   <script src="http://domain.com/application/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://domain.com/application/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://domain.com/application/scripts/customer_autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://domain.com/application/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" media="screen" type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet">

   </head>
<body>
      <div  data-role="page"  data-theme="a">
      <div class="wrap-header">
         <div data-role="header" data-mini="true"  data-ajax="false">
            <a data-icon="grid" data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" onclick="window.location.href='/sales'">Menu</a>
            <h3>New Sales Order</h3>
         </div>
      </div>   
      <div data-role="content">

         <label for="customer">Customer</label>
         <input type="text" id="customer" name="customer"/>


      </div>

   </div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The same issue applies even if my input is outside of any  elements. so just in body.

I must also mention that this is a codeigniter app, not sure if that plays any part.

Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps could you show the code from the head as it is rendered in html? It's hard to tell if it's broken by looking at the php.

Comment: Have you tried to include css after js?

Comment: Hi, I have added the rendered HTML. @Morpheus, css after JS did not assist. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you should set a background color (to white for example) to the dropdown men because it's in position absolute and you need to specify a background (and at least a z-index:1).

By the way provide some css and html to find out any problems.

Comment: Thanks @Claudio, this is the standard jquery ui download with no changes from myself. What element does the background color need to be associated with? and in which css / js file? Thanks, R

Comment: Try to do it in div="content". I never use JQueryUI (I always do it by myself with ajax & stuff) but I'm sure the problem is that.
Try to do this 1) Insert some text 2) When the box appear (in chrome) inspect that element 3) Find the parent div (and maybe the css that it uses) 4) edit it.